# How to pass data from view that came from an external API to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to pass a data from a view that was rendered from an external api to a controller to be able to save the ID to a model/database table.

This is my view:

```
<h1>Heroes</h1>
<% @response.each do |hero| %>
  <div class = "hero_wrap">
    <div class = "img">
      <img src="https://api.opendota.com<%= hero["img"]%>", id ="hero_img"/>
    </div>
    <div class = "fave_container">
    <%= link_to(image_tag('fave.png', class: "fave_img"), new_hero_path) %>
    <%= hero["id"]%>
  </div>
    <div class = "hero_name">
      <%= hero["localized_name"] %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
# heroes_controller

class HeroesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @response = HTTParty.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats")
  end

  def create
    @hero= Hero.new(params[:id])

    @hero.save
    redirect_to @hero
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/signup', to: 'users#new' 
  get  'pages/home'

  resources :pro_players
  devise_for :users
  resources :heroes
  resources :users

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

My hero model doesn't contain anything yet, I just want to pick the hero id and save it to my database.

[this is my web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbNXr.png)

server log upon clicking the star icon with link:

```
Started GET "/heros?custom_hero_id=1&method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 
2018-10-15 09:20:53 +0800
Processing by HerosController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"custom_hero_id"=>"1", "method"=>"post"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳/home/don/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering heros/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered heros/index.html.erb within layouts/application (42.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 770ms (Views: 83.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Updated log:

```
Started POST "/heros?custom_hero_id=21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-15 10:13:17 +0800
Processing by HerosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"PHDEXdDmPhPX+VdloU2y6yONY5HN5wI2lIfOaSbSKj9+RvTO5Ua3QPuTcreLZtGNDFPaSOXhDVyve6J69+1CQQ==", "custom_hero_id"=>"21"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      ↳/home/don/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/heros_controller.rb:9
      Hero Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "heros" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2018-10-15 02:13:17.032248"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-15 02:13:17.032248"]]
      ↳ app/controllers/heros_controller.rb:9
   (42.3ms)  COMMIT
      ↳ app/controllers/heros_controller.rb:9
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/heros/10
Completed 302 Found in 59ms (ActiveRecord: 46.9ms)


Started GET "/heros/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-15 10:13:17 +0800

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for HerosController):
```

Comment: In which column of the heroes table do you want it to save?

Comment: id column, I just want the hero["id"] to be saved.

Comment: What is the value you get for `hero["id"]`? integers?

Comment: Yes I get integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:id` attribute is by default a ***auto-increment*** attribute of datatype `integer` which sets its value under the hood **whenever a new instance of the model is created**. There are several ways to override the its behavior or setting its value explicitly, but considering that you are fairly new to the technology **I don't recommend** those for you. Instead I recommend a simpler solution of using **another attribute** to store `hero["id"]`

**Steps:**

1) Generate a migration to create a new column(say `custom_hero_id`) in the `heroes` table

```
rails g migration add_custom_hero_id_to_heroes custom_hero_id:integer
```

and do `rake db:migrate`

2) Change

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('fave.png', class: "fave_img"), new_hero_path) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('fave.png', class: "fave_img"), heroes_path(custom_hero_id: hero["id"]), method: :post) %>
```

3) Finally change your `create` action to below

```
def create
  @hero= Hero.create(custom_hero_id: params[:custom_hero_id])
  redirect_to @hero
end
```

**Update:**

Due to unknown reason, `custom_hero_id` isn't saving to the DB. Probably due to *forbidden attributes* error. Try changing it to

```
def create
  @hero = Hero.new(hero_params)

  if @hero.save
    redirect_to @hero
  end
end

private
def hero_params
  params.permit(:custom_hero_id)
end
```

Comment: It doesn't save the record, no begin and commit on the rails server.

Comment: @DonChristian can you update the question with the related server log?

Comment: @DonChristian My bad! The link should be `<%= link_to(image_tag('fave.png', class: "fave_img"), heroes_path(custom_hero_id: hero["id"]), method: :post) %>`. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: Oh, there's nothing wrong with the path I think. Can 'link_to' able to save through the database?

Comment: @DonChristian No! The code snippet has a slight change. Look closely here `heroes_path(custom_hero_id: hero["id"]), method: :post`

Comment: Only the other parenthesis deleted is the change I can see. But it's working.

Comment: Another problem, the column is saved as nil:
```Hero Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "heros".* FROM "heros" ORDER BY "heros"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Hero id: 8, created_at: "2018-10-15 02:07:36", updated_at: "2018-10-15 02:07:36", custom_hero_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> ```

Comment: @DonChristian What is the log now? Can you update it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store the hero id or it's name ?

I would advise to create a method in your heroe model. Something like

```
// heroe.rb

def save_api_heroes_to_db(response)
  response.each do |hero|
    unless hero[:localized_name].exists?
      hero.create(id: hero[:id], name: hero[:localized_name], image: hero[:img])
    end
  end
end
```

This method will save the heroe id, name and image in your database (unless it already exists).

You just have to call it in your `index` method, in your heroe controller.

Hope that helps.